# what is happening with .net object list?

Tags: vb.net, object, types

when I do something like

```
a = New List(Of Object)
a.Add(1)
a.Add("1")
```

Is there some information stored for each element, which type it is?

Comment: _Console.WriteLine(a(0).GetType())_

Comment: What kind of information you mean? In general you should avoid such lists, where you store different types as Object. You can always cast them where you process the items. For example with [`TryCast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/trycast-operator)

Comment: I get Strings which are either integers or normal strings. Both are valid value inside the information I read. By putting them into a list I know which position is which field. But I dont know the value so I cant cast depending on position

Comment: "Is there some information stored for each element, which type it is?" Yes.  For a primitive value type like an integer (your `1`) the process of putting it into an object is called "boxing".

Comment: It's usually frowned upon to keep different types in a list of objects, because it leads to brittle code and errors that are likely to arise at runtime instead of compile time.  When you talk about "which position is which field", my immediate reaction is that it indicates you should create your own class type to represent the info instead of trying to access it positionally in a common list.